# Tool for analyzing DNS config

Tags: bind

I have made dns using bind. Can someone recommend me some tool that I can paste the code in to test for errors?

Answer (score 1):

If your BIND master configuration file is, for example, `/etc/bind/named.conf`,
then you could use the `named-checkconf` tool that comes with modern versions of BIND (Debian-based distributions may package it separately into `bind9utils` package) to check it for errors:

```
named-checkconf /etc/bind/named.conf
```

If your configuration is complex and has several included files, this command will show all the configuration assembled into a single listing:

```
named-checkconf -p -x /etc/bind/named.conf | less
```

If you want to test any configured DNS zones, you can use:

```
named-checkconf -z /etc/bind/named.conf
```

There is also `named-checkzone` for checking the zone files more specifically.

You might also find in your distribution's list of available packages a separate `dlint` utility that can be used to check your DNS server for common problems. This utility works by contacting the DNS server and examining the specified DNS domain (and any subdomains, if they exist and you haven't specifically forbidden it).